# How to plot a function involving summation and logs in R

Tags: r

How to plot in R the following function

$l(\theta) = ln(\theta)*\sum{y_i} -n*\theta -n*ln(1-e^{-\theta})-\sum{ln(y_i!)}$

where the summations are from $i=1$ to $n$

I have the data set, but I know how to enter that already.

Comment: if you want to plot it, and `I` has the `y` values in the plot, and you have another variable `X` with the `x` values, you can just use `plot(X,I)`... you can also use `curve` if you want R to calculate your values (using Henry's function, for instance).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
L <- function(theta, y){ 
         log(theta)*sum(y) - 
         length(y) *(theta + log(1 - exp(-theta))) - 
         sum(lfactorial(y))
         }
L_theta <- function(theta){
         L(theta, y)
         }
#example
y <- c(1, 3, 5, 7)
L(2, y)
# [1] -11.4324
plot(L_theta, xlim=c(0, 2), xlab="θ" )
```

producing something like

[image]